# How to find xml node contains CDATA or PCDATA using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

friends anyone know how to find one node contain cdata or pcdata as innertext, any one help me.

```
<link>sample text</link>
<link><![CDATA[cdatacontent]]></link>
```

In this node link contains both CDATA and PCDATA, how to find difference

Comment: Please show a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - at least a well-formed input XML document, and the exact output you expect. It is [unclear what your problem actually is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

> any possible way to solve via xslt ?

No, because they represent the same data.

See [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/cdata.html#d2924e219):

> Text in a CDATA section looks exactly the same to the XSLT processor as text outside a CDATA section. For example,
>
> `<![CDATA[xxx]]>` looks exactly like `xxx`
>
> `<![CDATA[<>]]>` looks exactly like `&lt;&gt;`
>
> This is because they are intended to be equivalent ways of writing the same thing.